# change the horizontal-pod-autoscaler-sync-period with gke

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-platform

horizontal-pod-autoscaler-sync-period

How can I change this setting with gke?

I want to change from the default 30 seconds.

Comment: Sorry, it is typo. 30 seconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to add/remove flags when using GKE - that's the downside of it being managed *for you* and not *by you*.