# horizontal autoscaler in a GKE cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have  horizontal pod autoscaler running on GKE. It works but its slow to respond to increases in workload, so I would like to try modifying a couple of the kube-controller-manager parameters, specifically:

--horizontal-pod-autoscaler-upscale-delay
--horizontal-pod-autoscaler-downscale-delay

But the only CLI available seems to be kubectl. I have scoured docs and the client API but can find no way to do it, in fact this link suggested it may not be possible on GKE:

[change the horizontal-pod-autoscaler-sync-period with gke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46317275/change-the-horizontal-pod-autoscaler-sync-period-with-gke)

Does anyone know if there is a way to do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

These flags must be configured in the kube-controller-manager and since you cannot pass flags to the GKE cluster it is impossible to modify the autoscaler settings on GKE.

Comment: Thanks Lukas that saves me banging my head against the wall any longer :)