# Change the horizontal-pod-autoscaler-sync-period in EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have a k8s cluster deployed in AWS's EKS and I want to change horizontal-pod-autoscaler-sync-period from the default 30s value.

How can I change this flag?

Comment: Is the default 30s? The docs at https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/ say the default value is 15 seconds.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately you are not able do this on GKE, EKS and other managed clusters.

In order to change/add flags in [kube-controller-manager](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-controller-manager/) - you  should have access to your `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/` dir on master node and be able to modify parameters in `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml`.

GKE, EKS and similar clusters  manages only by their providers without getting you permissions to have access to master nodes.

Similar questions:

1) [horizontal-autoscaler-in-a-gke-cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47563575/horizontal-autoscaler-in-a-gke-cluster)

2) [change-the-horizontal-pod-autoscaler-sync-period-with-gke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46317275/change-the-horizontal-pod-autoscaler-sync-period-with-gke)

As a workaround you can [create cluster using kubeadm init](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/) and configure/change it in any way you want.

Comment: could you explain this workaround more? Do you mean the workaround is to not use GKE, and manage your own cluster? Or are you saying that you can create your own master node, then have GKE worker nodes connect to the master you created?